# how to remove a file from /opt?

Tags: files, uninstall

Ubuntu 12.4 LTS 64 Bit

I need to remove files that causing a problem in installing a program. The files are  in the directory `/opt` and the files are in the directory `/etc/polipo`.

Comment: how did you install the polipo tool?  In general, there will be a better way to fix the problem than by randomly deleting files...

Answer (score 8):

You can use the terminal as root, just open your terminal and type:

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/polipo/File
```

Or you can use:

```bsh
gksudo nautilus
```

To use Nautilus as root user.

Comment: i installed it normally sudo-apt-get install polipo

Comment: but its keep giving an error when its start dpkg